# Unable to convert string value into float

Tags: iphone, objective-c

when i convert a string value into float it takes o.oooo. here is the code.

```
  NSString *amt=txtTotalBill.text;
NSLog(@"%@",amt);
float amount = [amt floatValue]

NSLog(@"%f",amount);

NSString *insertData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tbl_Bills(Amount,Note,Due_On) values ('%f')",amount];
[database executeQuery:insertData];
NSLog(@"inert query: %@",insertData);
NSLog(@"value inserted");
[table reloadData]; 
[database close];
```

everytime it takes amount as 0.0000.In this code amt value is correct but that string value  doesnt convert into float.

Comment: What is printed out in the `NSLog(@"%@",amt);` line?

Comment: I tried your code its working fine at my end..Can you explain more and put some values to show what are you getting in the amt from textfiled text first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just tried some of your codeblock and it works out fine for me. The error could be in the NSString itself. Perhaps its not passing in a totally numerical number. Try using a CGFloat as well, although this shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've alreayd ensured that no non-numeric characters can make their way into the NSString thats to be converted.

Can you let us know whats the output you got for the NSLog for the string?

Could you also try setting an output format for the float? e.g. '%3.3f' will display 3 numbers each before and after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

Check txtTotalBill.text if the text is float number format.

If text is not float number format, [NSString floatValue] retuns 0.00000

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think this will work.

```
float amount = [txtTotalBill.text floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect

```
NSString *amt = txtTotalBill.text;
float amount;
amount = [amt floatValue];
```